# How to create LongListSelector with c# code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am new to development, I am trying to create LongListSelector with C# code but not succeeded.
Could anyone help me to create this.

My XML code is-

```
        <phone:LongListSelector ItemRealized="LLS_ItemRealized" Name="longList" ItemsSource="{Binding supportedList}" IsGroupingEnabled="False" LayoutMode="List" HideEmptyGroups="True" Margin="30,0,26,0" >
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="210"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="210"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Height="118" Width="209" Tap="ThumbnailImageTap" Margin="0" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ThumbnailUrl1}" Tag="{Binding ClipId1}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <Image Height="118" Width="209" Tap="ThumbnailImageTap" Margin="0" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ThumbnailUrl2}" Tag="{Binding ClipId2}"  Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Any suggestion to create this with C# will be great or any link related to my answer.

Thanks :)

Comment: you can look at this <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx>

Comment: Sorry @Darshan the link you have given can not found, check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by explicitly applying the style in the code behind. First of all define the LongListSelector with the predefined key.

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Key="listSelector" ItemRealized="LLS_ItemRealized" Name="longList" ItemsSource="{Binding supportedList}" IsGroupingEnabled="False" LayoutMode="List" HideEmptyGroups="True" Margin="30,0,26,0" >

                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="210"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="210"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Height="118" Width="209" Tap="ThumbnailImageTap" Margin="0" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ThumbnailUrl1}" Tag="{Binding ClipId1}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <Image Height="118" Width="209" Tap="ThumbnailImageTap" Margin="0" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ThumbnailUrl2}" Tag="{Binding ClipId2}"  Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Then get the style in the code behind and apply to the newly created LongListSelector.

```
var listSelector=new LongListSelector();
listSelector.Style=Resources["listSelector"] as Style;
```

Comment: my task is complete with different way. your idea seems to be good but since i am new not know how explicitly apply style in code behind, but I will try to do this.    Thanks for concern.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look here ?

Official microsoft link for "LongListSelector" on windows phone 8:

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PeopleHub-Windows-Phone-80-88abe94d

Template project from "CodeProject" on wp7 and wp8:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92439/Silverlight-DataTemplateSelector

I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Bind it on your own. Try this one.

```
LongListSelector listSelector;

private void CreateLongListSelector()
{
    listSelector = new LongListSelector()
    {
        HideEmptyGroups=false,
        IsGroupingEnabled=false,
    };
    ContentPanel.Children.Add(listSelector);
    listSelector.ItemTemplate = GetDataTemplate();

}

public DataTemplate GetDataTemplate()
{
    string xaml = @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
                    <Grid Background=""Transparent"">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width=""210""/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width=""210""/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height=""120""/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Height=""118"" Width=""209"" Tap=""ThumbnailImageTap"" Margin=""0"" Stretch=""Fill"" Source=""{Binding ThumbnailUrl1}"" Tag=""{Binding ClipId1}"" Grid.Column=""0"" VerticalAlignment=""Center"" HorizontalAlignment=""Left""/>
                        <Image Height=""118"" Width=""209"" Tap=""ThumbnailImageTap"" Margin=""0"" Stretch=""Fill"" Source=""{Binding ThumbnailUrl2}"" Tag=""{Binding ClipId2}""  Grid.Column=""1"" VerticalAlignment=""Center"" HorizontalAlignment=""Right""/>
                    </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>";
    DataTemplate res=null;
    try
    {
        res = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
    return res;
}
```