# How to pass data from CustomMessageBox to the page which called it?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a page where I call one **xaml layout page** as a CustomMessageBox which displays country list. I am displaying the country list with the help of LongListSelector. After selecting the country , I just want to close the CustomMessageBox and go back with the selected country to the page which called this CustomMessageBox. How to achieve this?
Here is the following code snippet :

FirstPage :

```
  CountrySelectionDialog countrySelectedDialog = new CountrySelectionDialog();
  CustomMessageBox cmd = new CustomMessageBox()
  {
        Content = countrySelectedDialog,
        Opacity = 0.9
  };
```

SecondPage i.e CountrySelectionDialog page :

```
  private void on_Country_Selection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.AddedItems.Count>0)
        {
            country = e.AddedItems[0] as Country;
             // Now how to go back with selected country to the original page?

        }
    }
```

Comment: try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271596/Customizing-MessageBox-on-Windows-Phone and http://shawnoster.com/2012/10/welcome-custommessagebox-to-the-windows-phone-toolkit/

Comment: I am not able to understand the references you have given. Can you please give a demo code or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following link  [How to create a LongListSelector control programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415370/how-to-create-a-longlistselector-control-programmatically)  and instead of creating a separate file as a CustomMessageBox, I created my own xaml file programmatically and called it in CustomMessageBox

Answer (score 0):

In the selection change event of long list selector use this code.

```
LLs_SelectionChange(....) 
{
String s= lls.SelectedItem;
MessageBox.close();
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/YourPage.xaml?country="+s),UriKind.RelativeorAbsolute);
}
```

And Get Country in your page using query string.

Comment: sry I edited my question. I am not using a MessageBox

Comment: Vinod. Please be clear also post some code snippet so that we can better understand what you are trying to ask. Tahanks

Comment: Yes I have added my code snippet. Hope you will understand this time.

Comment: Best way to do this don't use dialognbox to choose country. Use a LongListSelector directoly in your page,.
Country : LongListSelector Box.

Comment: I want to but I cant because of the requirement. Or else it would have been much easier for me

Comment: did you try this after your code?                 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/YourPage.xaml?country="+s),UriKind.RelativeorAbsolute);

Comment: Yes. I am getting an exception as follows : An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyProjectName.WinPhone.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: its because your selected value is not storing in string s. Use debugger and check whether selected country getting stored in variable or not

Comment: I used debugger and its printing the country name and id

Comment: ok. Try another option. Declare a property public static string country{get;set;}  in App.xaml.cs.  after getting vaue of country store it in this using App.country=lls.selecteditem. Then close your dialogbox. and you will be in the same page. Now set the content in your countrybox as App.Country

Comment: No its not that easy. After I select the country, the custommessagebox should automatically get closed and we should return back to the page which called this custommessagebox

Answer (score 0):

Use `IsolatedStorageSettings`

Example

```
IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings=IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
userSettings["Country"]=country;
userSettings.Save();
```

Add this after you get country, then add `NavigationService.GoBack()` and where you want country value, check whether country is stored in storage using below code

```
if(userSettings.ContainsKey("Country")
{
    country=userSettings["Country"];
}
```

The above will work if Country is string, if it is object you can use **PhoneApplicationService** to save the country value, then navigate back and check whether PhoneApplicationService contains `Country` object.

Comment: ok but do you know how to force close the customMessageBox as soon as we select the country ?

Comment: is this Windows.Phone.Toolkit customMessageBox?

Comment: Yes. m developing windows phone 8 app

Comment: There will be `customMessageBox.Dismiss()`, try that. add that line after you get country.

Comment: no. See ,  I am calling a PhoneApplicationPage from CustomMessageBox which I have mentioned in the code the way I am calling. Now how can I call customMessageBox.dismiss() in the same page? I even tried this.dismiss(). Its not available

Comment: on the same page you need to call. It should work, i have tried it many times. Also, instead of showing custommessageBox on different page, show on same page and when user selects country get the value and dismiss the custommessagebox.

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
private void on_Country_Selection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.AddedItems.Count>0)
        {
            country = e.AddedItems[0] as Country;
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.State("COUNTRY") = country;
               //close the page



        }
    }
```

now retrieve the country code wherever you want :

```
String countrycode  = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State("COUNTRY");
```